# How to respond for Openfire ping request with XMPPFramework

Tags: messaging, openfire, xmppframework

Am developing the messaging feature with Openfire and XMPPFramework combination. for checking the idle user status i enabled the server ping request.

how to respond to server ping request?
**server request**

```
<iq from='capulet.lit' to='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony' id='s2c1' type='get'>
<ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping'/>
</iq>
```

Comment: Myself found an answer that XMPPFramework provides a ping class it automatically responds to server ping. We can use that calss for auto ping-pong **code"1.var xmppping : XMPPPing = XMPPPing.init()  2.self.xmppping.respondsToQueries = true 3.self.xmppping.activate(self.xmppStream)" **here XMPPing is class And there one more class to autoping to server from client side**" 1.var xmppAutoPing = XMPPAutoPing()  2.self.xmppAutoPing =XMPPAutoPing.init(dispatchQueue: .main) 3.self.xmppAutoPing.pingInterval = 1 4.self.xmppAutoPing.pingTimeout = 1 5.self.xmppAutoPing.activate(self..xmppStream)"**

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is described in the XMPP extension protocol [XEP-0199 XMPP Ping](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html)

The desired response to an IQ ping is an empty result. In your example, this would be enough:

```
<iq from='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony' to='capulet.lit' id='s2c1' type='result'/>
```